# How to solve Python Memory Error ?. While loop does not stop running

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

this code is to find a subset of a string, which has unique characters.
make k  parts of the string and t then print these parts while not includeing the same character in the string

```
    def merge_the_tools(string, k):
        l = len(string)
        start = 0
        t = []
        ans = []
        while True:
            put=''

            for i in range(start,start+k):
                put += string[i]

            start = k
            t.append(put)
            if start + k == l:
                break

        for i in t:
            ss = set(i)
            s = ''
            for j in ss:
                s += j 

            ans.append(s)
            for i  in s:
                print(I)
   merge_the_tools('AABBAACC',2)
```

I think there is a problem with ,while loop which I'm not able to find.

Comment: You don't update k?

Comment: `k == 2`, `start = 0`, `l == 8`  - you break `if 0+2 == 8` and never increase `start` (0) or `k`(2) . ..  - use `print(...)` to debug your code and read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: ok i get it now ,thanks

Comment: now i did start =start+k and it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your need is not clear and I will respond with my understanding of your code.

you need to change the value of your start or k because here you will be stuck in start = 2 and k = 2.

Change the line

```
Start = k
```

by

```
start += k
```

it should work and stop running for infinite time.